Run xlsm macro in ssis package
How to export data from sharepoint to xlsm using macro and data should be autoprocess when sharepoint have new data?
I have implemented macro in xlsm file and   for automatic process I have implement logic using script task to run the macro code
using ssis. Script is not giving any error but data is not refreshing. It is showing old data in xlsm file.
I have created xlsm file  and open xlsm file go to query option there.
I have given SharePoint path details like below:=SharePoint.Tables("https://share.companyname.com/sites/rdh90e3kh53/rue/customersupport",[Implementation='"2.0",Viewmode="ALL"])
Sub Refresh_Customerconn()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshALL
End Sub

When I execute manually it ss working fine and getting latest data from SharePoint and loading in xlsm file. but when I call Macro using script task in ssis not getting latest data.
Mainly I want to automatic process to refresh the data in xlsm file . i.e I have implemented logic in ssis package and that package I will
schedule it using sql server agent job. but macro is not refreshing in ssis script task.
string filename = "C:\\Users\\Ravo\\Desktop\\CustomerReport.xlsm";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename); 
xlApp.Visible = false; 
xlApp.Run("Customerformat"); 
xlWorkBook.Close(true); 
xlApp.Quit();
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;


I think what you are trying to do, is to have your Excel macro run automatically when the file is open. To do so, you have to put your code in the Workbook.Open event so it executes automatically when the file is opened - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open

Make sure your macro is working perfectly
Sub Refresh_Customerconn()
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub

Mke sure Loading Excel,Running Macro and closing workbook is in sequential way
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public void Main()
{
    string filename = @"C:\Users\Ravo\Desktop\CustomerReport.xlsm";
    Application xlApp = new Application();
    Workbook xlWorkBook = null;

    try
    {
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename);
        xlApp.Visible = false;

        // Run the macro to refresh data
        xlApp.Run("Refresh_Customerconn");

       //Save the workbook if you want to keep the updated data
        xlWorkBook.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Excel Script Task", ex.Message, "", 0);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clean up
        if (xlWorkBook != null)
        {
            xlWorkBook.Close(true); // Save changes
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
        }

        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}


it is showing error in this linek "Application xlApp = new Application();" Application is an ambiguous reference between micorsoft.officeinyrtop.excel.applicaton and system.windows.forms.applications  could you please help on it

Hmmm..I hin  ambiguity issue arises because both Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application and System.Windows.Forms.Application are referenced, and they both have a class named Application. To resolve this, you can explicitly reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application by fully qualifying the type...let me edit it

and also when i execute it showing this will cancel a pending data refresh. continut? and it is not refreshing.

Set BackgroundQuery Property: and create a wait loop..This ensures all refreshes complete synchronously. Lemme dit my second code

We used such setup during ours initial SSIS setup with sharepoint for new integration. And its been an year..lemme know if it works,otherwise i have look for new methods,may be some metods got deprecated..will look into API documentation

Try this and update if its working
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;// Alias namespace Excel 


public void Main()
{
    string filename = @"C:\Users\Ravo\Desktop\CustomerReport.xlsm";
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;

    try
    {
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename);
        xlApp.Visible = false;

        // Set BackgroundQuery to false for synchronous refresh
        foreach (Excel.QueryTable query in xlWorkBook.Connections)
        {
            query.BackgroundQuery = false;
        }

        // Run the macro to refresh data
        xlApp.Run("Refresh_Customerconn");

        // Wait for refresh to complete
        while (xlApp.Refreshing)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);  // Wait 1 second before checking again
        }

        // Save the workbook with the refreshed data
        xlWorkBook.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Excel Script Task", ex.Message, "", 0);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clean up
        if (xlWorkBook != null)
        {
            xlWorkBook.Close(true); // Save changes
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
        }

        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}

